# Will Other Mobs Spawn in a Slime Chunk

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

In my world, I've cleared out an entire chunk, from bedrock to about 90 (ground level).  It is a slime chunk, and slimes are spawning in the bottom.  At level 40, I constructed several hostile mob spawning pads.  They are dark, and have a large enough area for mobs to spawn.  But the strange thing is, they're not spawning at all.  During construction of the pads, there were a couple of skeletons, zombies, and a creeper, but nothing near what you'd expect from an entire empty chunk.  There are no slimes preventing spawning, and I've AFK'd for quite a while beyond 24 blocks from the pads.

So my question is, do normal hostile mobs (zombies, etc) not spawn in slime chunks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes other mobs will spawn in a slime chunk. The thing that is affecting your spawn rates are the chunks surrounding your spawning chunk. If memory serves there is a sphere surrounding the player. 128 blocks in all directions. Inside of which mobs can spawn. So what is going on here. Is that the mobs you are wanting. Spawn elsewhere. Light up caves in the surrounding area. Or strip mine the whole area. (the method I use.)  There is a useful image on the minecraft wiki page regarding spawning. If I were slightly more tech savy I would have provided it.

Happy crafting.

Comment: Thanks.  Then it sounds like the easiest way to do it is to re-build it up in the air, then AFK at 128 blocks above ground in order to maximize its output.

Comment: That solution may work. You might want to look into it before you build. As I think vanilla minecraft has a cap in the hight that mobs can spawn. Really sorry. Your best bet is to get spelunking. And light up the area. But I have noticed better spawns in a sky farm. With out having lit anything up.

Comment: I did hear that spawning really high was causing problems, but that they can be fixed by adding more blocks above it.  It won't look for places to spawn way up in the air for performance, so you have to go farther up to make it register as an area to search.

Comment: Your right jonah. I remember now watching a youtube video of someone putting an antenna like structure above their farm. There Is something else for you to look into OP.